# How to send variable dynamically from grunt command line to grunt copy task

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I am trying to integrate grunt with Jenkins and having one issue while copying files.

I am trying to pass the file path dynamically from grunt command line so that user can select the path dynamically. Because our version no keeps changing.

So I declared at top of gruntfile.js

```
var pathValue="";
```

So I have a task called

```
grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['copy']);
```

I am reading the path from commandline as below

```
grunt --target=\\\\machine1\\versionno\\js\\

var target = grunt.option('target');
```

My Copy sytax looks as below

```
copy: {
          main: {
            files: [
              // includes files within path                  
              {expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['dest/**'], dest: **pathValue**, filter: 'isFile'}        
            ]
          }
        },
```

But somehow the value is not getting set to that variable

Am I missing something? please let me know.

All I want to do is send the value from command line to the destination directory dynamically

Thanks

Comment: I assume the asterisks are not actually present in your Gruntfile? Also try adding `console.log(target);`right after setting it to see if it is actually retrieved from the command line.

Comment: no asterisks are part of formatting.

Comment: Have you tried logging the variable to console?

Comment: I didn't try that,I will try today and update you Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if that's only something wrong with your example or not but you are never setting the pathValue to your option, try:

```
pathValue = grunt.option('target');
```